# FeatureRequest : javascript - Executable code like in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With the advent of LWC, Salesforce is adopting the JS more. And we're getting more JS/HTML related questions. Can we have a executable code snippets(like fiddler), which will show output in the answer itself.

This way it'll avoid the wrong expectations and more interactive way to provide answer.

PS- This feature is present on stackoverflow.com as shown in below picture.

[image]

Comment: I've seen a conversation that with Salesforce closing the LWC playground they will instead be [moving to WebComponents.dev](https://twitter.com/ntotten/status/1316842784448557058). That perhaps isn't as convenient as the integrated JS execution, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: yes that can be an alternative substitute and traditional fiddlers as well. However it'd be very useful if it comes at the answer only.